# Newsyslog wildcards - rotate all logs in a directory

Tags: logging, freebsd, log-files

I am running FreeBSD 8.1. I am trying to make newsyslog rotate logs defined by a dynamic path:

```
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/path/logs/*.log    644  7     100  $D0   J
/path/logs/*/*.log  644  7     100  $D0   J
```

Basically I want newsyslog to rotate all files ending with .log in directory /path/logs/.

i also  want to do the same for all subdirectories of /path/logs/ which is the second line of my config file.

But when I do:

```
newsyslog -F
```

No log files get rotated.

Comment: Try running `newsyslog -nv` and see if it throws any errors.

Comment: Side note: by default the archived log files will be placed in the same directory, and will have the new name service.log.0.bz2; meaning they will be picked up by newsyslog again because you've got an asterisk at the end of your glob pattern. This is almost certainly not the behavior you intend.

Comment: @Chris S Thanks. Yeah I removed the wildcard from the end. Also all that was needed to make it work was to use -G flag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the `G` flag in `/etc/newsyslog.conf` helped:

```
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/path/logs/*.log    644  7     100  $D0   G
/path/logs/*/*.log  644  7     100  $D0   G
```

Comment: Congrats! Looks like the flag `G`, for `glob(3)`.

Comment: Reading `man newsyslog` helped as I see.